# Imagemagick Thumbnailing PDF with multiple pages

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I am currently using Imagemagick and the thumbnailer I have works, but the problem is that when its a multiple page PDF, it thumbnails only the Last page.

Preferably I want it to thubnail the first page only. Can anyone shed any light.

```
    if(in_array($ext,array('pdf'))){

                $pdf = './uploads/'.$new_file_name;

                $filename=str_replace($ext,'jpg',$new_file_name);

                $img = new imagick($pdf);

                for ($x = 1;$x <= $img->getNumberImages(); $x++) {      
                    $save_to = './uploads/'.$x.'-'.$filename;
                    $img->setImageFormat('jpg');
                    $img->resizeImage(149,211,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
                    $img->displayImages('img');
                    $img->writeImage($save_to);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you'll need to set the image index with each iteration.

```php
for ($x = 1;$x <= $img->getNumberImages(); $x++) {
  $img->setIteratorIndex($x - 1); // nth - 1 assuming we're starting with `$x = 1'      
  $save_to = './uploads/'.$x.'-'.$filename;
  $img->setImageFormat('jpg');
  $img->resizeImage(149,211,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
  $img->displayImages('img');
  $img->writeImage($save_to);
}
```

**Update:**

A `while` loop my provide an easier solution with [Imagick::hasNextImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.hasnextimage.php) and [Imagick::nextImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.nextimage.php).

```php
$img = new imagick($pdf);
while($img->hasNextImage()) {
   // ... do work
   $img->nextImage();
}
```